# Not able to capture Enter key in WinForms text box

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2008

When the user is entering a number into a text box, I would like them to be able to press Enter and simulate pressing an Update button elsewhere on the form.  I have looked this up several places online, and this seems to be the code I want, but it's not working.  When data has been put in the text box and Enter is pressed, all I get is a ding.  What am I doing wrong? (Visual Studio 2008)

```
private void tbxMod_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        btnMod.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Comment: Try this solution...it's working....

 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Button is pressed");
        }

        private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
        {   if(e.KeyChar=='\r')
            {
                button1.PerformClick();
            }
        }

Here the code that will allow you to press the button when you press enter in the textbox....check it out....

Answer (score 9):

Are you sure the click on the button isn't performed ? I just did a test, it works fine for me. And here's the way to prevent the "ding" sound :

```
private void tbxMod_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        btnMod.PerformClick();
        e.SuppressKeyPress = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

A few thoughts:

- does the form have an accept-button (set on the `Form`) that might be stealing <kbd>ret</kbd>
- does the textbox have validation enabled and it failing? try turning that off
- does something have key-preview enabled?

Comment: a) Nope
b) I'm validating input within the _Click function using int32.tryparse, but that's only after the Click event happens.  I tried commenting the entire function out and just putting in a MessageBox and it still didn't work.
3) Looked on the form control - key preview is off. 

I also went through the next four responses below.  Nothing seems to do the trick so far.

Answer (score 2):

Under "Properties" of the Form. Category (Misc) has the following options:

AcceptButton, CancelButton, KeyPreview, & ToolTip.

Setting the AcceptButton to the button you want to have clicked when you press the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key should do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

I had to combine Thomas' answer and Marc's. I did have an `AcceptButton` set on the form so I had to do all of this:

```
    private void tbxMod_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AcceptButton = null;
    }

    private void tbxMod_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AcceptButton = buttonOK;
    }

    private void tbxMod_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
        {
            // Click your button here or whatever
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
```

I used t0mm13b's `e.Handled`, though Thomas' `e.SuppressKeyPress` seems to work as well. I'm not sure what the difference might be.

Answer (score 1):

Set `e.Handled` to `true` immediately after the line `btnMod.PerformClick();`.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

form properties > set KeyPreview to true

Answer (score 0):

The simple code below works just fine (hitting the Enter key while in textBoxPlatypusNumber displays "UpdatePlatypusGrid() entered"); the form's KeyPreview is set to false:

```
private void textBoxPlatypusNumber_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
    {
        UpdatePlatypusGrid(); 
    }
}

private void UpdatePlatypusGrid()
{
    MessageBox.Show("UpdatePlatypusGrid() entered");
}
```